Cannot resolve symbol 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' even though I have it in my pom.xml
I am trying to create my security config file and have downloaded the spring-boot-starter-security dependency in my pom.xml. This is how it looks in my pom.xml:
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

This is my security config code and I will talk about the lines that have errors:
package com.Lumber.LumberIntegration.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() // Permit access to login page
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login") // Custom login page
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout
                                .permitAll()
                );
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("customUser")
                .password("{noop}customPassword")
                .roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }
}

The import statement:
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

has an error and I am not too sure but I think that might be causing a problem for the whole file. I have also tried restarting my maven project but besides that I have not done anything. I am not sure how to restart my caches or if that would even work. Any help is much appreciated thank you so much in advance!

What Spring Boot version are you using? That class was deprecated about 2 years ago and removed with Spring Security 6.

"In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration."

oh I see ok thank you so much!
